# Unwanted texts showing up on top of home page

Tags: pimcore

I am using the latest version  of `PIMCORE` using my design skills only. Two days ago a strange line appeared on top of my home page.

> **); ga('set', 'anonymizeIp', true); if (typeof _gaqPageView != "undefined"){ ga('send', 'pageview', _gaqPageView); } else { ga('send', 'pageview'); }**

and this line is not going away. It is visible in all browsers. Inside `PIMCORE` though I do not see it on top of my home page. Please help me get rid of this line from my site. [This](http://www.digitalimpact.dk) is the site address.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have a setting for google analytics somewhere in your Website Settings. You pasted in there the whole JS code for GA but you should instead put in there the GA identifier i.e UA-78793038-1.

If this is not the case, please show us the whole code of your  section - probably in /website/views/layouts/layout.php

Comment: Spot on, Igor! I have removed the code and the line has disappeared. Many thanks.

Comment: @NahinMamun Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.